# Conservation of energy in a sound wave

Tags: energy, waves, energy-conservation, acoustics, spherical-harmonics

I have two ultrasonic transducers, an emitter and a receiver, and I'd like to know how the energy of the spherical wave is conserved. I guess the energy is proportional to its amplitude and it decreases as $1/r^2$, but I'm not sure if what is seen by the microphone is that amplitude or something else.
Thank you very much

Comment: couldn't you measure that?

Comment: Yes I did measure it, and it fits more or less well to the curve $1/r^2$ , but I want to be sure of the theoretical expected behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Energy is proportional to amplitude squared.  The energy in the wave is spread out over the surface of a sphere.  The area of this surface increases as the wave propagates outwards from the source and is proportional to $r^2$.  So the intensity of the wave (power/area) decreases in proportion to $1/r^2$.